# Create a fake Rails request object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actioncontroller

I'm trying to write tests for a gem that adds some functionality to ActionController::Base. I want to do something like this:

```rb
class TestController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render json: { foo: "bar" }
  end
end

RSpec.describe "foo" do
  it "foo" do
    controller = TestController.new
    controller.process(:index)
  end
end
```

However, when I do it errors out with `undefined method 'has_content_type?' for nil:NilClass` because request [here](https://github.com/jamesstonehill/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb#L287) is `nil`.

How do I create a "fake" request object so I can set it on a controller like this:

```rb
    controller = TestController.new
    controller.request = ?
    controller.process(:index)
```

Comment: It is not common to test rails controllers directly instantiating them and calling the methods (because, as you have experienced, there is no request object). I would suggest using the RSpec guidelines for testing controllers https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Comment: @Bustikiller I'm having some trouble replicating an rspec controller test outside of the context of an Rails app. Do you have an example for how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have such examples. However, the code in your question looks pretty much like a rails application. What do you mean with "outside the context of a rails application?

Comment: @Bustikiller these are tests for a gem that adds some functionality to actionpack so there is no application context in the tests.

Comment: The closest I have been to that is creating a rails engine (special kind of gem) that adds some models, jobs and controllers to the application including it. In this kind of projects it is common to have a dummy test application including the gem against which tests are run. This provides a rails test environment where you can seamlessly use RSpec the same way you would do in a regular rails application

Answer (score 2):

A controller needs a lot of information from the environment to parse information into a request object. As such it is probably too convoluted and prone to break if you try to set it up yourself.

Have a look at the documentation of [`ActionController::TestCase`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html): even though it is discouraged in favor of integration tests, this might be a scenario where a functional test is more appropriate.

Then there is also `rspec-rails`: its controller test methods should be quite helpful if you want to construct a temporary controller in your tests. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-6/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Comment: I explored the anonymous_controller route first but ran into difficulties getting rspec-rails to work without a full Rails app booted. Are there any examples of a gem using `rspec-rails` to test action_controller extensions?

Comment: What difficulties did you encounter? You could go the way of the Rails engine and host a separate dummy application that uses your gem inside the `spec/dummy` folder. See [this article](https://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-126-how-to-setup-rspec-in-a-rails-engine) for a quick intro.

Comment: Specifically `Rails.application` is `nil` which is causing errors like 
`undefined method `routes' for nil:NilClass` when it tries to run a `type: :controller` spec.

Comment: Here is the commit in which I try the rspec anonymous controller method as well as the `ActionController::TestCase` method. In both cases it seems the frameworks assume a full Rails environment so I get errors like `NoMethodError: undefined method 'routes' for nil:NilClass`

https://github.com/jamesstonehill/api_error_handler/commit/bff955aa0530750c529ef0365f0bc9e5d5582ca8

Answer (score 0):

There's rarely any reason to fake a controller unless you're doing some major low-level work, like working on Rails core. I've done it previously for a batch controller and simulating a full request is very complicated due to all the extra value Rails provides. Even if you do manage to fake a full request-response cycle, you'll miss out on a lot of subtle features and corner cases, which defeats the purpose of the test.

I would instead lean on the standard integration testing infrastructure, i.e., verify your gem by checking that a controller using it will process things as expected. You can also use a mock framework like Mocha if you want to verify certain of your functions are being called, but even that is usually overkill.